# Obtain kernel config from currently running Linux system?

Tags: linux, kernel

I accidentally deleted my .config for my kernel configuration on Linux, and seem to remember there was a way to retrieve the kernel configuration via the proc filesystem somehow.

Is this still possible, and if so how would I do it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/577307/how-to-get-a-list-of-active-drivers-that-are-statically-built-into-the-linux-ker || http://askubuntu.com/questions/163304/which-device-drivers-are-built-into-the-kernel || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376540/view-linux-kernel-config-options || http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83319/how-can-i-know-if-the-current-kernel-was-compiled-with-a-certain-option-enabled || http://serverfault.com/questions/51032/how-do-i-check-what-kernel-options-were-compiled-without-looking-at-boot-config

Answer (score 189):

Depending on your system, you'll find it in any one of these:

1. `/proc/config.gz`
2. `/boot/config`
3. `/boot/config-$(uname -r)`

and possibly more places.

Comment: On some distros (Fedora/Redhat) it's /boot/config-2.6.18-194.el5 or similar, with the kernel release string appended.

Comment: @Phil I run a distro (Zenwalk) where those filenames are symlinked by the latest kernel package to `/boot/config`. I'll go ahead and add these to the list - thanks for reminding me.

Comment: in /boot/config-$(uname -r) for amazon linux and likely RHEL

Comment: Not existing such files on Ubuntu Mate or Kali Linux for RaspBerry Pi.

Comment: You should mention that your first item (/proc) is only available if module "configs" is loaded

Comment: Note that you can use `zgrep CONFIG_OPTION /proc/config.gz` if you want to search for a specific option without unzipping a copy of the config file.

Answer (score 83):

For an actual running kernel, one way to get the config file this is to

```
cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip > running.config
```

or,

```
zcat /proc/config.gz > running.config
```

Then `running.config` will contain the configuration of the running linux kernel.

However this is only possible if your running linux kernel was configured to have `/proc/config.gz`. The configuration for this is found in

- `General setup`

  - `[*] Kernel .config support`

    - `[*] Enable access to .config through /proc/config.gz`

Most distributions do not have this configuration set. They provide kernel config files in their kernel packages and is usually found in `/boot/` directory.

Comment: These are known as `CONFIG_IKCONFIG` and `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC`, if you're grepping for them.

Comment: `zcat /proc/config.gz` works fine.

Comment: `less /proc/config.gz` also works fine

Comment: @nocnokneo for me that failed (offered to show me the binary file) but `zless` worked

Answer (score 54):

A Little bit late but maybe it helps someone. I didn't have `/proc/config.gz` nor `/boot/config` nor `/boot/config-$(uname -r)` on my Computer. I had to run `modprobe configs` as root. Then, `/proc/config.gz` was present

Comment: Can confirm on Intel MIC embedded Linux (BusyBox), this is necessary and works.

Comment: Same for Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 2

Comment: `FATAL: Module configs not found.` on OMV 2.2 (Debian Wheezy) so glad they provided it in /boot/config-$(uname -r)

Comment: You sir, saved my day. Have a +1

Comment: 'modprobe configs' is very helpful  I had tests that automatically probe kconfig that were failing on a Raspberry Pi 3, but now work.  Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: On WSL, `modprobe: FATAL: Module configs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-18362-Microsoft`. So that is where /proc/config.gz comes from.

Answer (score 25):

Regardless of the distribution, you can run: `cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/.config`

Source: [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page (search for `/proc/config.gz`).

Comment: Unfortunately neither this no any other solution here works to get the kernel config on a Netgear ReadyNAS.

Comment: This one works great with raspbian . Thanks.

Comment: This one works great for raspbian. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

If you couldn't find kernel configuration in /boot/ nor in /proc/config.gz, you can try extracting this information from the kernel itself.

Inside any kernel source code there is a script for extracting config located in `scripts/extract-ikconfig`, pass the kernel you want its configuration as parameter to this script.

This solution will only work if `Kernel .config support` was enabled in the compiled kernel.

Comment: This was extremely helpful and helped me to obtain plenty of configs I didn't expect to ever see. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you can't find any of the suggested files and you are able to `modprobe` you should almost always be able to get a copy of the current config this way.

```
modprobe configs # might need `sudo modprobe configs`

# This will create /proc/config.gz
zcat /proc/config.gz

# Or if you are looking for whether a specific option was set
zgrep USBIP /proc/config.gz
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but I'm not sure enough kernels ship with the configs module available.  I couldn't find it on the Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 systems I had handy.

Comment: I found it useful specifically on ChromeOS where they don't include the compressed configs but do include the module to export the running config if so desired.

Answer (score 2):

For RedHat-based distributions, the .config file of the off-the-shelf kernel can be found with the command `cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/.config` that's available after the package kernel-devel is installed using the command:

```
yum -y install kernel-devel
```

Note that with the *real* Red Hat Enterprise Linux distribution, you will need to enable the source-repository to get this package. On RHEL8, use the following command to do that:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-source-rpms
```

Answer (score 2):

Run `modprobe configs` as root to create /proc/config.gz

After that `zcat /proc/config.gz > /boot/config-$(uname -r)` to list config of the kernel.