# How to get a list of active drivers that are statically built into the linux kernel?

Tags: drivers, linux-kernel, kernel-module

While I can use `lsmod` in order to show currently active kernel modules, how can I see which drivers are statically built into the kernel AND currently active?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could do a `cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin`

From the Kernel [Documentaton](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kbuild.txt)

### modules.builtin

This file lists all modules that are built into the kernel. This is used
by modprobe to not fail when trying to load something builtin.

Comment: modules.builtin does not exist in my system with uname: Linux ecp 4.4.127-1.el6.elrepo.i686 #1 SMP Sun Apr 8 09:44:43 EDT 2018 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux.  Is there another way to find what drivers are built in?

Comment: @Danny Make sure you use `uname -r` and not the more common `uname -a`

Answer (score 11):

If your linux has a /proc/config.gz

That has all the built modules.  Copy it elsewhere and unzip it.  Open the file everything with a  "=M" is built as a module.  Everything with a "=Y" is statically built.

hwinfo will list the "Driver:" check the above file to see if it is statically built.

FYI:  All statically built drivers are always loaded into memory and ready for action.  Without the corresponding hardware they will not do anything, but use memory.

Comment: What if there is no `/proc/config.gz`?

Comment: Ok I just found a .config file in the directory where I compiled the kernel, that's obviously what you meant.

Comment: This file also exists here: `/boot/config-$(uname -r)`.

Comment: no need to unzip if you just want to see. Just `zcat /boot/config-$(uname -r)` or `zcat /proc/config.gz`. You can also use `zgrep` or `zmore`

Answer (score 7):

The sysfs module area `/sys/module` is a view into all the modules visible to the running kernel.  Each module directory has a set of sysfs interface files to view and manage the module via userspace.  Generally speaking, the LKMs have a `refcnt` file, which will be greater than 0 if it is being used along with a `holder` directory of those modules using it.  The builtin modules do not have this file (or many others like `initstate` and `taint`.)

Try `find /sys/module -name refcnt -printf '\n%p: ' -exec cat {} \;` to see which are being used.

Under many modules is a `parameters` directory containing the parameters that can be viewed and modified from user-space.  In the source this is generally a call to a `module_param` macro.  For example, see `kernel/printk.c` and the module `/sys/module/printk/parameters` for some useful printk tuning.

All entities under `/sys/module` are set in the kernel module framework. Some are hardware drivers, some are netfilter, some are filesystems, some debug, etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
ls /sys/module
```

seems to contain all built-in and external modules.

But it also appears to contain some entries which are not actually modules: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225706/are-modules-listed-under-sys-module-all-the-loaded-modules

TODO: read the source and understand more precisely what gets put there.

The advantage of this method is that you don't rely on being able to find the kernel config under `/boot` or `/proc/config.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to comment on cybernard response, but without reputation on this specific StackExchange service I can't.

To quickly check `/proc/config.gz` against some specific module, you don't need to unzip it anywhere (useful when you don't want to write to any partition of your device):

```
$ gunzip -c /proc/config.gz | grep 8021Q
CONFIG_VLAN_8021Q=y
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1092272)

Comment: no need to gunzip. Just `zgrep 8021Q /proc/config.gz` is enough